# Swift animatewithduration extra argument "delay" in call

Tags: xcode, swift

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        let theWidth = view.frame.size
        let theHeight = view.frame.size
        if (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height == 568) {

            if (textField == self.profielnameTxt) {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
                    self.view.center = CGPointMake(theWidth/2, (theHeight/2)-40)
                    }, completion: {
                        (finished:Bool) in
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code. and I keep getting extra arugument 'delay' in call when I try to build it. I am banging my head and searching google all over, but I can't find out where is wrong

Comment: Try to clean your project and build again.

Comment: I just tested your code and it build without error.